# Laravel Join Two Table, Get NULL ROW if Record not found

Tags: mysql, laravel

Let's consider two tables, "users" and "data"

"users" table data (total number of rows -> 2)->

```
user_id      name         email
1            Test      test@test.com
2            Try       try@try.com
```

"data" table data (total number of rows -> 1)->

```
data_id     user_id    json_field
1               1           {}
```

Using Laravel Join

```
DB::tabe("users")->join("data" , "users.user_id" , "=" , "data.user_id")->get();
```

The about query returns only one row, which is

```
user_id      name      email            data_id    json_fied
  1          Test    test@test.com         1          {}
```

But, I want to get the result of two rows like below:

```
user_id      name      email            data_id    json_fied
  1          Test    test@test.com         1          {}
  2          Try     try@try.com          NULL       NULL
```

Any idea?

Comment: You are probably looking for `leftJoin` instead `join`.

Comment: So what are differences in results when you do a `join` vs `leftJoin`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `join` use `leftJoin`.

**Explanation:**

The `join` is `INNER JOIN` and it selects records that have matching values in both tables.

The `leftJoin` is `LEFT JOIN` and it returns all records from the left table (in your case `users`), and the matched records from the right table (`data` table). The result is `NULL` from the right side if there is no match.

Comment: @JohnyPie this is an entirely different question and should be asked separately.